# Encode folder labels stored in a numpy array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on a Parkinson dataset.
In my dataset folder, there are two folders : [image]

In two of each, there are two other folders but that's really a detail:[image]

in which...:

[image]

Now, in my code i'm doing a feature extraction and a label extraction here's my attempt:

(I've used the split function to get the name of the folder as you can tell in line 12.)

```
from imutils import paths
import numpy as np
import sys
import cv2
import os
import mahotas as mt
data =[]
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
pathswave=r'C:\Users\Bsi\Desktop\PFE2\Base2\dataset\wave'
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(pathswave))
for imagePath in imagePaths:
   label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
   image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
   image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   image = cv2.blur(image,(3,3))
   image = cv2.resize(image, (200, 200))
   textures = mt.features.haralick(image)
   feat = textures.mean(axis=0)
   data.append(feat)
   data.append(label)
print(np.array(data))
```

Here's a portion of the output:

[image]

Now is there any way to convert the two labels, 'parkinson' and 'healthy' to two distinct integers ( preferably 0 and 1, (1 being 'parkinson).

Answer (score 0):

3 numbers, in case its not either :)

```
x = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
label = '0' if x == 'healthy' else '1' if x == 'parkinsons' else '-1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a dictionary:

```
my_dict = {'healthy': 0, 'parkinsons': 1}
```

You can later get 0 or 1, by accessing the elements using get:

```
my_number=my_dict.get(label)
```